# Maintaining the previous items after the update listview

Tags: android, listview, initialization, updating, notifydatasetchanged

I have a problem with updating my `ListView`. I don't want to lose my `ListView`'s data after the first initialization.
I searched on this site and some other sites and found different solutions. At last I used the below code, but I didn't get any result.

```
private void handelpost(List<Posts> posts,Page pages) {
    ListView listView;
    final CustomListAdapterForPostOrgan adapter;
    if (pages.getCurrentPage() > 1) {

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_for_post_organ);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapterForPostOrgan(this, posts);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    } else {

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_for_post_organ);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapterForPostOrgan(this, posts);



        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: Those blocks of code differs only by notifyDataSetChanged, which is useless in this case. Can you please explain more details? Could you please tell me why you're using adapter initialisation here? Does this method invoked only once? Or you recreate adapter every time?

Comment: I have a list view that recieve 2 items in every connection. I want to upload my list view everytime that I recieve new data and at the same time I don't want to lose my previous data. This is my first time and I do't have any experience. Just this and no more detail. Could u help me please.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating new Adapter with new data every time. Which is not advisable when you're working with pagination. You need to do following changes.

1. Declare your adapter and list view and an **ArrayList** class level.

   ```
   public class MyActivity extends Activity{
        private ListView mListView;
        private CustomListAdapterForPostOrgan mAdapter;
        private List<Posts> mPosts;
   }
   ```
2. Initialize your `ArrayList`, then Adapter and then set it as adapter to ListView once in `onCreate()` of `Activity`.

   ```
   private void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate();

         //After you've called setContentView() etc etc.
         mPosts = new ArrayList();
         mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_for_post_organ);
         mAdapter = new CustomListAdapterForPostOrgan(this, mPosts);
         mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   }
   ```
3. When you receive new data, first add it to your class-level array and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` like this:

   ```
   private void handelpost(List<Posts> posts,Page pages) {
         //add new posts to existing array..
         mPosts.addAll(posts);
         //since adapter already has your array, simply make it refresh.
         mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   ```

Comment: //since adapter already has your array, simply make it refresh.

Comment: Could you explain more about it  
//since adapter already has your array, simply make it refresh.

Comment: You already passed array `mPost` in adapter when creating adapter `CustomListAdapterForPostOrgan(this, mPosts);`